# exact width and height of fixed-width character

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a text widget that needs to have fixed with font for displaying tables and such. To be able to count the amount of character that fit into a given window I need to have the height and width of the font that I am using. I whipped up a quick function that calculates it by creating an element with a single character and get the height and width of that element. The problem is that this width and height are integer not floats. For instance if I call this function on chrome with `1em` fontSize and fontFamily `monospace`. I get width 8 and height 15. The height value is correct but the width is actually something like 7.14... This doesn't seem much but when you start to have 100 characters on a line you can see that the offset becomes more than 80 pixels.

Is there a way to get the accurate values in some reliable way?

and please no jquery..

here is the function:

```
function getCharDimensions(fontFamily, fontSize) {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    var el = document.createElement("span");
    el.style.position = "absolute";
    el.style.top = "-100%"
    el.style.fontFamily = fontFamily;
    el.style.fontSize = fontSize;
    el.innerHTML = "x";
    body[0].appendChild(el);
    var dimensions = {
        height: el.offsetHeight,
        width: el.offsetWidth
    };
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    return dimensions;
}
```

Comment: make the string 'x' 100 characters long and then divide the result by 100 (or 1000 characters long and divide the result by 1000 etc..)

Comment: @DorianFM yes I could but this seems rather clunky to get an accurate reading to 3 significant figures I would need 1000x1000 which takes around half a second on my pc.

Comment: Create a dummy `div` and feed the `sentence` to be tested for being fittable. Now reduce the number of characters efficiently until text is not overflowing. Note that characters can take different amount of space (XilW)

Comment: @sabithpocker my use case is a resizable container so if I were to resize I would have to rerun this type of function. It's doable but I feel that might be even more expensive. Also I am using fixed-width so all characters take the same amount of space.

Answer (score 0):

You are not consideering the tracking and the kerning of the typography. All characteres have a tracking defined to adjust it to other characters and be more readable.

In this case this is not the only thing that affects you, it's because CSS can't read decimal pixels in a normal screen with device pixel width 1. So `1.5px` doesn't exists.

If you detect a pattern you can apply to the font size and remove the tracking in your letter, and you can apply the `7.14px` because you can make a sum with it and it will be more accuracy than now.

Good luck!

### EDIT

As a improvement, you can define the character you are looking for the width and height, because an `i` have less width than a `m` (yes, I know that you are playing with monospace, but this is a good improvement).

```
 function getCharDimensions(character, fontFamily, fontSize) {
       //stuff
       el.innerHTML = character;
       //stuff
  }
```

Comment: why do I care about tracking per character. Afaik the total character width is not changed by this only where the glyph is actually situated inside the character space. I could do it by making the test very large. something like 1000x1000 but this seems like a hack rather then something "real".

Comment: The most important aspect that you need to take in care is the 8px width because 7.14px is not valid. But if you sum 7.14+7.14+7.14 ... the final result will be more real.